# Elisp while function not working

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to write a loop in a skeleton function. It should be very simple but its not working and suggests that I don't understand [loop functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Incrementing-Loop-Details.html#Incrementing-Loop-Details) in ELISP. I have the following:

```
(define-skeleton test
  ""
  ""
  '(setq i 1)
  (while (< i 5)
  '(setq i (+ i 1)))
  )
```

When I evaluate this I get an infinite loop. What is going on?

Comment: There is a `dotimes` function you can use: `(dotimes (i 5) (do-stuff))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes, which treat the forms as data.  You should also `let`-bind your local variable `i`, or else it will bind a global variable instead.  You need to evaluate as such:

```
(define-skeleton test
  "A test skeleton."
  (let ((i 1))
    (while (< i 5)
      (setq i (1+ i)))))                ; (incf i) would also work
```

A little more detail: `(setq i (1+ i))` is a list (and so is `(1+ i)`), but the reader knows to treat it as a form to evaluate when the first item in the list is a function call, a macro, or a special form (like `if`).  When you quote a list (either by prepending an `'` or wrapping it in a `(quote ...)`), it tells the reader to treat the whole list as data, returning it unevaluated.

So, `(setq i (1+ i))` binds `i` to the value of 1 plus whatever `i`'s value was previously, `(setq i '(1+ i))` binds `i` to the unevaluated list `(1+ i)`, and `'(setq i (1+ i))` simply returns itself as the unevaluated list.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! For some reason I had the impression I needed quotes to stop setq from giving unnecessary output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in skeletons, the "quote" is special but only at the "top-level".  I.e. you need to change your `(while (< i 5) '(setq i (+ i 1)))` to `'(while (< i 5) (setq i (+ i 1)))`.